# sql combining rows of the same primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql

[In here you can see the nested or statement which allows me to combine the answers.text and answers.integer to the same table in some order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmYu1.png)

[But what I would like to do is have the integers and text on the same row if they have the same submission id. How would I do that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVjcc.png)

EDIT: The concat was supposed to combine the two on the same line, or so I thought. But it had just took out the nulls from the columns so that there were only two -> submissions and building_idquant. When before there was submission_id, building_id, and integer.

Comment: This is what JOINs are for: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read this page so you can write questions based on the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And which DBMS is this meant to work with, given the fact you've tagged 3?

Comment: Everywhere I have seen has treated postgresql the same as sql. Sorry for the misunderstanding, should I have just tagged postgres?

Answer (score 1):

its tough to  get your expectation from image but i thought after seeing your image you need below somethin

```
select submission_id,building_idquant ,
    concat(CONVERT(varchar(50), submission_id),building_idquant ) as id_quant from
    (
    select distinct submission_id,building_idquant from tablename 
    ) t
```